# Simple parabola

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

How do I find the equation of the parabola below? 
I got $y = \frac{1}{4}x^2$

But I'm quite sure about this. [image]

Comment: The picture is nice but can you show your work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parabola must be of the type $y=ax^2$, for some $a>0$. The focus of that parabola is $F=\left(0,\frac a4\right)$. The slope of the line passing through $F$ and $(2,4a)$ is$$\frac{4a-\frac a4}2=\frac{15a}8.$$And you want it to be equal to $\frac12$. So, which $a$ should you take?

Comment: $4/15$? I think

Comment: Absolutely right!

Comment: Thank you for this